# How do I access a function in a function from another .py file

Tags: python

Hi im currently trying to implement bfs on python

im trying to access a nested function in a function from another .py file but im unable to do so may I know if there's any workaround this?

this is my code

```
def get_path(start, end):
result = []
distance = 0

# Map generation
bus_stops = json.load(open("unique_bus_stops.json", "r"))
bus_stops_distance = json.load(open("bus_stops_distance.json", "r"))

# Maps bus stop name to bus stop dictionary
bus_stop_map = {bus_stops["name"]: bus_stops for bus_stops in bus_stops}

# Maps bus stop id to bus stop dictionary
bus_stops_distance_map = {bus_stops_distance["bus_stop_id"]: bus_stops_distance for bus_stops_distance in
                          bus_stops_distance}

# Maps bus to list of bus stops
# {bus: [bus_stop1, bus_stop2, ...]}
# For BFS graph
routes_map = {}
for routes in bus_stops_distance:
    key = routes["bus"]
    if key not in routes_map:
        routes_map[key] = []
    routes_map[key] += [routes]

# Generate graph
# {bus_stop_id: [bus_stop_id, bus_stop_id, ...]}
graph = {}
for bus, path in routes_map.items():
    for i in range(len(path) - 1):
        if path[i]["bus_stop_id"] not in graph:
            graph[path[i]["bus_stop_id"]] = []
        graph[path[i]["bus_stop_id"]] += [path[i + 1]["bus_stop_id"]]

# BFS algorithm
def bfs(graph, start, end):
    # Keep track of all the paths to be checked with queue
    queue = Queue()

    # Keep track of all the nodes that have been visited
    viewed = set()

    # Insert the first path into the queue
    queue.put([start])

    # Keep looping until there are nodes still to be checked
    while not queue.empty():
        path = queue.get()
        node = path[-1]

        # If the current node has not been visited
        if node not in viewed:

            # Check if the current node is the end
            if node == end:
                return path

            # If the node is viewed, continue
            if node in viewed:
                continue

            # Mark the node as viewed
            viewed.add(node)

            # Add all neighbours to the queue
            for neighbour in graph.get(node, []):
                # Create a new path and push it into the queue
                new_path = list(path)

                # Add neighbour to the new path
                new_path.append(neighbour)

                # Push the new path into the queue
                queue.put(new_path)

# Translate bus stop id to bus stop name
def getBusStop(index):
    # For each bus entry in routes_map
    for bus, route in routes_map.items():

        # For each bus stop in the route
        for index2 in range(len(route) - 1):
            # If it is the first or last bus stop, skip
            if bus_stops_distance_map[path[index]]["lat"] == 0 and bus_stops_distance_map[path[index]]["lng"] == 0:
                return None
            # Return the bus stop name
            return (
                 bus_stops_distance_map[path[index]]["lat"], bus_stops_distance_map[path[index]]["lng"],
                # bus_stops_distance_map[path[index]]["name"]
                # bus_stops_distance_map[path[index]]["bus"],
                # bus_stops_distance_map[path[index]]["bus_stop_id"]
            )
```

the function that I am trying to access is getBusStop(index). Im currently trying to implement it to my app.py file and I want to use it to check if ['name'] it exists in my json file

Comment: where is your import part? Sth like from sth import sth?

Comment: Best and easiest way is to move the nested function to the outside and then just import it to your new module. `from file import function_name`